# #1114 - table is full when I tried to add new user to a specfic database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to add new user to a specific database, but I get an error that table 'db' is full. I don't even have a table name 'db' so I'm confused.

My step:
I went to --> User Accounts --> Edit Privileges --> Database --> click on the database that I wanted the user to have privileges --> Check the checkbox -> click GO.

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON  'database name'.* TO 'username@localhost';

MYSQL said:

#1114 - The table 'db' is full

I'm able to change global privileges successfully, but when it is Database-specific privileges, I get error.

so how do I fix this?? I went to my.ini, but not exactly know what to do.

Comment: The MySQL ERROR 1114 can be triggered when you try to perform an INSERT statement on a table. To fix this error, you need to first check the disk space in where your MySQL server is installed and see if the partition is really full

Comment: I didn't perform INSERT statement on a table. I'm just trying to add user's privilege to a specific table and not global.

Comment: GRANT does insert rows to tables in the `mysql` schema, and `mysql.db` is one of these tables. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/system-schema.html